# Как организовать взаимодействие компонентов? Через сервис + rxjs или через output/input?

Tags: javascript, angular2

Вопрос по Angular. Есть форма для адреса и в ней есть инпуты. Форма - родительский компонент. Инпуты - дочерние. Инпут города зависит от инпута страны. Если в стране вбита Россия, то в город можно вводить только русские города. Как вы организуете общение между компонентами в таких случаях? Через Input/Output декораторы, или через rxjs? Вообще реально ли организовать такое через rxjs и не потерять возможность повторного использования дочерних компонентов в рамках другого родителя?